# Textbox readonly but editable on add new, SQL bound windows form C#

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

I want to see a `TextBox` value only for a `TextBox` when moving through the sql table items

But when I click on the <kbd>Add new</kbd> button the `TextBox` must be editable for the new item

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the TextBox property ReadOnly to false in the click button.

Comment: Thank you it works perfect now. I added TextBox.ReadOnly = true on delete and save button so it changes back when i add a new item.

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you add a event to add on the `bindingnavigator` you can change `ReadOnly` property of the textbox

Answer (score 0):

In the button OnClick action change the TextBox property ReadOnly into false. And return it back to true when another condition is satisfied (of your choice).